# Changing Selection color in Ubuntu 18.10 themes

Tags: gnome, themes, customization

I use **Ant Dracula** theme for my Ubuntu. But selection color is **Pink** color, which I want to change to different color.

How can I change?

Theme Link is https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1099856/

[image: Pink color on home]

and on firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we need to edit the file gtk.css

access the file by

`sudo -H nautilus /usr/share/themes/Ant-Dracula/gtk-3.20/gtk.css/` change `/usr/share/themes` if you stored your file in `~/.themes`

find the color `#ff79c6` and change it to your preferred color in the initial lines.
it has major effect on themes.

```
/* GTK NAMED COLORS
   ----------------
   use responsibly! */
/* widget text/foreground color */
@define-color theme_fg_color #f8f8f2;
/* text color for entries, views and content in general */
@define-color theme_text_color #f8f8f2;
/* widget base background color */
@define-color theme_bg_color #1e1f29;
/* text widgets and the like base background color */
@define-color theme_base_color #282a36;
/* base background color of selections */
@define-color theme_selected_bg_color #ff79c6;
/* text/foreground color of selections */
@define-color theme_selected_fg_color #f8f8f2;
/* base background color of disabled widgets */
@define-color insensitive_bg_color #22232e;
/* text foreground color of disabled widgets */
@define-color insensitive_fg_color #8b8c8e;
/* disabled text widgets and the like base background color */
@define-color insensitive_base_color #282a36;
/* widget text/foreground color on backdrop windows */
@define-color theme_unfocused_fg_color #8b8c8e;
/* text color for entries, views and content in general on backdrop windows */
@define-color theme_unfocused_text_color #f8f8f2;
/* widget base background color on backdrop windows */
@define-color theme_unfocused_bg_color #1e1f29;
/* text widgets and the like base background color on backdrop windows */
@define-color theme_unfocused_base_color #2a2c39;
/* base background color of selections on backdrop windows */
@define-color theme_unfocused_selected_bg_color #ff79c6;
/* text/foreground color of selections on backdrop windows */
@define-color theme_unfocused_selected_fg_color #f8f8f2;
/* widgets main borders color */
@define-color borders rgba(25, 26, 34, 0.9);
/* widgets main borders color on backdrop windows */
@define-color unfocused_borders rgba(26, 27, 35, 0.91);
/* these are pretty self explicative */
@define-color warning_color #ff9f39;
@define-color error_color #ff3c3c;
@define-color success_color #4caec3;
```

there are 67 entries with the color #ff79c6, i have replaced all of them with #456789 in single shot. if you want to try each individual, you have to make trial and error of those 67 entries.

save the file & Close. Reboot to see the change.

[image]

Comment: I had thought of similar solution. But I was not able to find the exact color. How did you find it was this `#ff79c6` color.

Comment: its generally bg_color some thing related to background.

Comment: Please relook at "sudo -H nautilus /usr/share/themes/Ant-Dracula/gtk-3.20/gtk.css/". `gtk.css` is a file not a folder.

Comment: @DKBose yes, when you run `sudo -H nautilus /usr/share/themes/Ant-Dracula/gtk-3.20/gtk.css/` it will get selected and ready to open when you press enter.